# Get all conversation from Azure Bot

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I want to get all the conversation from azure bot.
Is there any possible options to get the chat logs from application insights.
Is there any option to get all the active conversations (ConversationId).
Please suggest.

Comment: I would suggest to save chat history in some database and retrieve the chat history as per your need. Hope this helps

Comment: So, there is no direct way to get those details?

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights does contain all the information to track conversations (including ConversationId).  I would recommend reviewing the Analytics information included with the Virtual Assistant.

[Virtual Assistant Analytics](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/readme.md#analytics)

It contains an overview of how that solution uses Analytics and includes a transcript example. The transcript tab in the PowerBI workbook will show a transcript.